# How to Remove Quotes Surrounding Text Returned From CSV File Parse

Tags: vb.net, parsing, csv, split

I am using the code below to compile a list of ticker symbols on the NASDAQ stock exchange.  I am using the CSV file located here: http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&render=download

When I open the CSV file in Excel there are no quotation marks around the ticker symbols.  But when I run the code below.  All of the ticker symbols returned to my list have quotation marks around them.  Why is this?  And how do I get rid of the quotation marks?

Here is my code:

```
Public Shared tickerList As New List(Of String)
Dim compositeList As New List(Of String) 
Dim strBuffer As String
        strBuffer = Historical_Stock_Prices.RequestWebData(http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&render=download)
        Dim sReader As New StringReader(strBuffer)
        Dim Line_List As New List(Of String)
        Do While sReader.Peek >= 0
            Line_List.Add(sReader.ReadLine)
        Loop
        Line_List.RemoveAt(0)
        For Each Line In Line_List
            compositeList.Add(Line.Split(",")(0).Trim.ToLower)
        Next
        sReader.Close()
tickerList = compositeList.Distinct.ToList
tickerList.Sort()
```

Comment: Don't use .Split() to parse csv data. There are a number of dedicated csv parsers out there that can do a much better job: [FastCSV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader), [Linq-To-CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library), [EasyCSV](https://github.com/jcoehoorn/easycsv), and [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) all come to mind.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: [KBCsv](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/) is what I used - works very well. Some 70K records parsed per second or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
compositeList.Add(Line.Split(",")(0).Trim(New Char() {""""}).ToLower)
```

Comment: @gromit1: If DonA's answer was helpful, don't forget to accept and/or upvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
myString = myString.Substring(1, myString.Length -1)
```

That will remove first and last characters.